# How to organize this loop in a more elegant Pythonic way

Tags: python, loops, iterator, do-while

So I have a function which reduces some dataset, and returns the number of elements removed. I have to stop applying it once the number of items reduced during the function's operation is zero. Currently I've got this:

```
num_removed = reduction_pass(dataset)
while num_removed > 0:
    num_removed = reduction_pass(dataset)
```

but these two variable assignments kind of get to me. Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you don't actually need the final return value, as I assume it indicates the number of removed elements, which will obviously always be 0 on the last pass.

The simple-is-better-than-complex way:

```
while reduction_pass(dataset) > 0: pass
```

The showing-off, obviously-not-serious way:

```
from itertools import *
list(takewhile(lambda x: x > 0, starmap(reduction_pass, repeat((dataset,)))))
```

Comment: That's less variables assignments and valid, but that's a bit obscure!

Comment: The main reason that the simple way throws you off is that we normally expect an expression used in that context to be "pure", i.e. without side effects. Here, we're using it explicitly for its side effects. It's a bit like abusing the third part of a `for` statement in C or C++.

Comment: I find the simple way to be very readable (if not for the slightly superflous need of "pass") which in my eye is part of goal in programming. Though maybe that has to do with my being used to reading/writing quite a bit C code too where this sort of construct is used all the time :p

Comment: Excellent! just what I needed

Comment: I hope you mean the first one! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an iterator with

```
it = iter(lambda: reduction_pass(dataset), 0)
```

which, on every step, calls the given function and stops when 0 is retrieved.

With this iterator, you can do

```
for num_removed in it:
    do_whatever()
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the 2-argument form of `iter`. That definitely beats my `itertools` module hackery. :)

Comment: This is an interesting approach but a bit overkill in my case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python doesn't allow statements inside the conditions control structures. It has its pluses, and it has its minuses.

If you find the two var assignments so annoying, maybe this is better:

```
while True:
  num_removed = reduction_pass(dataset)
  if num_removed <= 0:
    break
```

Although generally I don't think you should worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to me is:

```
num_removed = None
while num_removed is None or num_removed > 0:
    num_removed = reduction_pass(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop with a break in it is usually simplest and best, however assuming that when you said to loop while `num_removed > 0` you might actually have meant `num_removed != 0`, here's a fairly clean alternative:

```
for num_removed in iter(lambda: reduction_pass(dataset), 0):
    pass
```

That only makes sense of course if you actually need the intermediate values of `num_removed` for something inside the loop body.